# wp-content is being called wrong by localhost wordpress install

Tags: wordpress

I have found some links on this, but nothing has really been specific. I got wordpress to load onto my local computer. It is at localhost\wordpress. But all of my content files are trying to load from localhost/wp-content/ and leaving out the wordpress folder I set up. Anyone have a link or can explain the solution to rerouting the wp-content folder I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to set the right url in your settings.
Read about it on http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

You'll also have to change the old urls in your database. The most easy way is to dump your data in a sql file, empty your database, use find and replace in any text editor to modify your .sql dump, save it, and then import the dump in your database again.

Comment: I added this
define('WP_HOME','http://localhost/wordpress');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost/wordpress');
to the config.php file but it does not seem to do anything to the links.

Comment: Are you using a new/empty database? or did the database run on a other site before?

Comment: The database was imported in from the live site.
I changed the home and siteUrl database values now too and that did not change anything. I feel it could be related to the theme I am using, whiteboard1. But I am not sure.

Comment: There were some html calls being made in a theme. Thanks for your help in troubleshooting this though.

Answer (score 0):

There are two entries in your wp_options table that you need to check. One is `siteurl` and the other is `home`. Those should both be set to whatever directory you have WordPress installed in.

You can also add these two lines to your wp-config.php file.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

More [information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) on that.

Comment: I did that and it has no effect on the paths being called.